# Vertical scrolling not working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I have two `ion-scroll` elements on my page, the top one scrolls horizontally, below it is a list that should scroll vertically.

The problem is it doesn't. It just bounces back to the top of the list.

Example: http://codepen.io/CaffGeek/pen/LEVdVY

I have found that if I set a height on the vertical ion-scroll it 'works' but this needs to work on multiple devices and I don't know what height to use. I'd prefer to not have to watch events, and recalculate the height each time. Anybody know how to fix this?

#### HTML

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Ionic List Scroll Bug</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic List Scroll Bug</h1>
    </header>

    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <ion-scroll delegate-handle="calendarScroll" direction="x">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-20" ng-repeat="day in payPeriod.days">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">{{day.name}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">{{day.number}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-scroll>

        <ion-scroll delegate-handle="taskScroll" direction="y">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-80">
                            <p>{{task.name}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-20">
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Hours" ng-value="task.time" />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
          </ul>
          </ion-scroll>
  </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar align-title="right" class="bar-stable">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button">Save</button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Total hours 0.00</h1>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.payPeriod = {
            days: [{ name: 'Mon', number: 3 }, { name: 'Tue', number: 4 }, { name: 'Wed', number: 5 },
                { name: 'Thu', number: 6 }, { name: 'Fri', number: 7 }, { name: 'Sat', number: 8 }, { name: 'Sun', number: 9 }]
        };
  $scope.tasks = [
    {name: 'task 1', time: 1.0 },
    {name: 'task 2', time: 3.0 },
    {name: 'task 3', time: 2.0 },
    {name: 'task 4', time: 1.0 },
    {name: 'task 5', time: 2.0 },
    {name: 'task 6', time: 1.0 },
    {name: 'task 7', time: 1.0 },
    {name: 'task 8', time: 2.0 },
    {name: 'task 9', time: 1.0 },
    {name: 'task 0', time: 1.0 }
  ];
});
```

Comment: Use a density independent unit such as a `vh` unit then, or scope everything around the root font size and use `rem`.  Unfortunately, this is just how `ion-scroll` works.  It needs a defined height in order to run its calculations, otherwise it's getting a `NaN` and calculating from `0`

Comment: seriously...what's with the neg votes on a question, that's asked, answered, and not flagged?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

## [Codepen illustrating a simple fix](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emNrOm)

Here's the meat of what we're doing:

```
ion-scroll[direction=x] {
  width: 100vw;
}
ion-scroll[direction=y] {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

That will allow your scrolls to work as expected in your Ionic app (and, in fact, this is what I do in mine as part of the CSS boilerplate).

## GIF: in action on CodePen

[image]

Comment: maybe it's me, but that doesn't appear to be working (at least not in Chrome)

Comment: @CaffGeek – What isn't working for you?  What environment is it not working in?

Comment: I reloaded the page, and it's scrolling now, but not actually scrolling to the last item in the list. I think it's because 100vh doesn't take into account the size of the header, footer or horizontal scroll area. Which comes back to the issue of having to recalculate the size.

Comment: @CaffGeek – Alright, I'll take it the rest of the way for you.

Comment: I added a 25vh height div to the bottom of the list, as a buffer, seems to allow me to scroll to where I need now.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I updated the `CSS` version, but the JavaScript I was working on got way too complicated way too fast.

Comment: For anyone trying this: Be aware that this will not work on some Android versions as the browser does not support viewport units: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: its working on the browser but not on my device. any idea? android version 4.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Hybrid work-around for you to try:

Maybe it's not the best solution, but at least allows for scrolling, for you to try, if you like:

Just wrap your whole page content into a `<div>` with absolute position and define whether to scroll y and/or x:

```
<div style='position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x: hidden'>
    <!-- your content of page here .... -->
</div>
```

Worked for me. Browsers compatibility on Windows 10, using ionic-package for Meteor JS (without Angular JS):

**:-) shows scrollbar on**:
 - FireFox
 - Windows 10 Edge 
 - MS IE 11

**:-( Does not show scrollbar, but it scrolls:**
 - Safari
 - Chrome
 - Opera

Hope this helps a bit for some cases.